# Column truncated with a relation to another entity

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

When I try to update the schemes, I get the following error :

```
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE TechSummaryRdvDocuments CHANGE carRegistration_i  
  d carRegistration_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE idCardRecto_id idCardRecto_id VARCHAR(255) NOT N  
  ULL, CHANGE idCardVerso_id idCardVerso_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE vehicleInspection_id vehicl  
  eInspection_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE idCardRectoPartOwner_id idCardRectoPartOwner_id VARCHA  
  R(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE idCardVersoPartOwner_id idCardVersoPartOwner_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL':      

  SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'idCardRecto_id' at row 848
```

It is defined this way in my entity :

```
/**
 * @var FileValid
 * @ORM\Column(name="idCardRecto_id")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Carizy\CoreBundle\Entity\FileValid", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $idCardRecto;
```

Where `FileValid` is an entity with differents fields.
Do you know how I can fix it ?

Comment: What is the content of row 848?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some data already in your existing database table where the idCardRecto_id column value exceeds the new column length of 255 characters (which is the default length of the string column as you don't have any explicit column definitions written)? I.e. you can define the max length of that column to be something bigger to match your existing data, like:

```
@ORM\Column(name="idCardRecto_id", length=1000)
```